# how to add space before a tag in beatifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have the following piece of code:

```
html = urlopen(req).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
# remove all script and style elements
for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
    script.extract()
# get text
text = soup.get_text()
```

The problem is that if in my html page I have something like
`Oxford<br />Laboratory`, and
after removing the style, I get `OxfordLaboratory`

So here is my question: how can I add a space, before all `<` so that words do not get combined?

Answer (score 2):

As the [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) states:

> You can specify a string to be used to join the bits of text together:
>
> ```
> # soup.get_text("|")
> ```

In your case you'll want a space (`" "`) as the separator.

Comment: Thank you very much for your rapid answer. It works!

Comment: mustaccio, wanted to ping you, would you please take a look at my Meta post "[Merge/cleanup tags \[zos\], \[mvs\], \[zseries\], and \[mainframe\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370743/merge-cleanup-tags-zos-mvs-zseries-and-mainframe)" and comment as someone who has much more knowledge about these tags than I do?